# UPLOAD FILE VULNERABILITY with multer

Tags: node.js, express

I am using multer to upload file in my application. 
like: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/README.md

Can path [traversal vulnerability possible](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) ? If yes then tell us how we can stop this?

Currenlty, I am using below code. I just want to confirm, Is there any file vulnerable risk? Please comment.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(file);
    var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
    cb(null, Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname);
}});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    // Accept or reject the file based on if MIME type is found in accepted list
    if (acceptedMimeTypes.indexOf(file.mimetype) < 0) {
        return cb("エラー：このタイプのファイルはアップロードできません。ZIP形式とLZH形式のファイルのみアップロードしてください。", false) // Error: You can't upload files of this type. Please upload images and zips only.
    }
    else {
        return cb(null, true);
    }
}
var upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter, limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1 } }).single('file');
```

If there is any risk then please suggest me a better approach with expressjs multer.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the fileName using this code so no one can threaten you :

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './public',
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'Your File Name');
  },
});
```

and also you can make it dynamic using `randomatic` and `time` like this :

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './public',
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${new Date().getTime()}`);
  },
});
```